# How to prevent first chapter on page two when table in header of pdf generated with iText?

Tags: java, pdf, itext

When having a PdfPTable in the header of the document, the first Chapter added gets added too page two, leaving the first page blank. If having just text in the header all works fine (see the out commented line in code sample). Am I doing something wrong or are there a workaround for this problem? I'm using iText-2.1.7.

So to be clear: The code below generates a pdf with one empty page as the first page and if going with the out commented row instead there is no empty page first.

Another thing is that if having a table in the header the generated header gets no height making the text of the document placed over the header table. That one I can work around. But it could perhaps give some help in understanding what's happening...

```
    Document vDocument = new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(vDocument, new FileOutputStream("C:/Test.pdf"));

    PdfPTable vTable = new PdfPTable(1);
    vTable.addCell(new PdfPCell (new Phrase("Header text")));
    Phrase vPhr = new Phrase();
    vPhr.add(vTable);

    HeaderFooter vHeaderFooter = new HeaderFooter(vPhr, false);
    // HeaderFooter vHeaderFooter = new HeaderFooter(new Phrase("Header text"), false);
    vDocument.setHeader(vHeaderFooter);

    vDocument.open();
    vDocument.add(new Chapter("New Chapter", 0));
    for (int i=0; i<1000; i++) {
        vDocument.add(new Paragraph(" TEXT " + i));
    }
    vDocument.close();
```

Comment: The `HeaderFooter` class has been removed from iText a long time ago (and replaced by page events). iText 2.1.7 is not supported because it dates from July 2009 and also [for these reasons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25696851/can-itext-2-1-7-or-earlier-can-be-used-commercially). Hence you should not expect an answer to your question. `Chapter` is also being abandoned in favor of `PdfOutline`. Moreover: your code is wrong. You don't add anything to the `Chapter`.

Comment: Adding the Paragraphs to the Chapter makes no difference...

Comment: Adding a table to a phrase doesn't make sense in iText 2.1.7. We're not in 2009 anymore. Use a more recent version and we'll be happy to help you.

Comment: I am unfortunately for now forced to use the old version... My workaround will be to remove the empty page after the document is created.

Comment: Forced by whom, by what? If by a person, is that person aware of [the legal implications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25696851/can-itext-2-1-7-or-earlier-can-be-used-commercially)? If there is a customer involved, is the customer aware of the suboptimal solution?